# Functional programming passing dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, functional-programming

I would like to know what is the common and good method for making dependency injection in Functional programming.

For example if I have 2 modules (DB and User).

The user module accepts Db module.

But should I send each Db function in User module or the whole Db object.

I mean this (in JS):

```
const User = {
insert(inserted, userData) {

},
delete(deleter, userId) {
}
}

User.insert(Db.insert, {username: 'asd', admin: 1..});

User.delete(Db.delete, 123);
```

or this:

```
function User(db) {
  return {
    insert(userData){..}
    delete(userId){..}
}
let usrs = User(Db)
usrs.insert({username..}).
usrs.delete(123)
```

As you see the second example code is less but it's still object oriented.

In the first example I have to pass the Db function each time I call method from User module. Maybe over time it will get very messy.

Can you suggest if there is better way to do it.
So if in future I change Db object (mysql from sqlite for example) I have to change it in only one place.

Thanks

Comment: I was wondering if DI, which is really an OOP concept, even made sense with functional programming... [this article](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/dependency-injection-1/) tends to imply *"sort of"* :) ... if you focus on the goals of DI rather than the implementation. Thought it might be worth a nose.

Comment: Both of these are hardly "functional". Although you can also consider that using the object is just to collect similar function together (more like a namespace) rather than using *methods*. Still, A more functional approach is the first one combined with currying - each function *has* to have the database to make inserts into. It wouldn't be reaching into a global state. But if you curry them, you can make `insert :: db -> user`, so you don't have to pass the database all the time. With this in mind, the *second* code block is closer to a functional approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at [this series of articles](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2017/01/27/from-dependency-injection-to-dependency-rejection/) on this exact topic, by Mark Seeman. Mark is a frequent post on SO so he may be along to expand.

To overly simplify, there a a few approaches depending on your complexity, and your desire for functional purity.

The simplest is just to take dependencies as arguments to functions. So you define your dependencies at the 'outside' of your code and 'inject' them to the core via arguments. For more complex scenarios you may not like the many extra arguments this can lead to.

More complex projects can make use of partial application and 'impure/pure/impure sandwich' discussed by Mark. However, some FP purists insist on pure functions only in the core of their code.

For FP purists there are other techniques but these are typically only useful in pure functional languages. Mark might disagree on this point though.

The use of some of these techniques will be limited by the support your language of choice has for FP. For example, I am not aware that JS has function currying, then again, I have very limited experience with JS.
You might also want to try a FP language that trans-compiles to JS, like F#/Fable or Purescript.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write your own dependency-injection engine - use exusting one e.g. [here](https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js). Good approach is to create `User` class and inject `DB` object to `User` constructor (and save it as [private](https://jamie.build/javascripts-new-private-class-fields.html) field of `User` class). Even better approach is to create `UserService` which have injected `DB` and allow to operate (e.g. read/write) on `User`s models.

Comment: A `User` *class* does not sound very FP to me.

Comment: I want to understand how are managed the dependencies in FP languages. Even if JS is not real FP the example can be done in JS so I can understand the paradigm.